# how can I sort an array which change 2n with 2n+1 index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which is :

```
array = ['a','c','b','d','f','e','g','i','h',...]
```

and I want to change it to:

```
result = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',...]
```

I want to swap the (2n-1)th of the array with (2n)th, for instance swap 'b' and 'c' . how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a start index and a delta and swap the value at index with the next value of the array.

```js
const
    swap = (array, i, delta) => {
        while (i < array.length) {
            [array[i], array[i + 1]] = [array[i + 1], array[i]];
            i += delta;
        }
        return array;
    }
    array = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'h'];

console.log(...array);
console.log(...swap(array, 1, 3));
```